# How to fix BSOD on windows 10? It says Critical Process Died

Tags: boot, bsod

I encountered the BSOD on my Sony Vaio three months back after a windows 10 cumulative update and since then I've had trouble booting my laptop. The first time it happened, it said registry files were missing or corrupted. I tried all troubleshooting options that I found online, extensively, but to no avail. And the syste wont let me reset the pc either. So I reinstalled windows 10 as a last resort, after which I was able to log in, but the BSOD appeared again after windows updated itself and I restarted it. This time it says Critical Process died. I used a memory diagnostics tool which said I had a memory-related hardware issue but running another tool on my pc to check for Hard drive health, it shows no issue. I've had to reinstall windows several times and I've tried system restore as well. But the BSOD returns with a boot loop after running the pc for a couple days. Usually occurs after I restart the pc. Also, booting under Legacy instead of UEFI gives a black screen that keeps printing "No operating system found".

I know this is a dense problem, but any leads, conclusions or fixes(i can only hope) would be appreciated.

Info regarding pc: 2nd or 3rd gen, 500gb hdd, 4gb RAM(upgraded to 12gb), model name:SVE15136CVB
TIA

Comment: You've probably got hardware issues. What does the Event Viewer say?

Comment: @music2myear The event viewer shows several critical error logs saying "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly" however i kept it plugged in at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run chkdsk while troubleshooting the issue by any chance? There is also a chance that the boot is corrupted.

1. To run chkdsk, run the Windows 10 setup (if you have it).
2. Then once you get to the **Install now** screen, click on the **Repair my Computer.** Click on **Troubleshoot** and select **Command Prompt.**
3. Then type `chkdsk C: /f /r` and hit Enter *(wait for that to finish)*.
4. In the command prompt, type the following commands:

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```